# How find this $a_{n}$ such $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(\dfrac{a_{n+1}+1}{a_{n}}\right)^n=e$

Tags: limits

if postive sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ such
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(\dfrac{a_{n+1}+1}{a_{n}}\right)^n=e$$
 find  a example the $a_{n}$ such this condition?

This problem is from analysis book : show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{a_{n+1}+1}{a_{n}}\right)^n\ge e$$
and I can't  prove this.But I can't find this inequality when :$=?$

Comment: Not sure I understand: if $a_n=1$ then the limit is $\gt e$.

Comment: sorry,@Did,I have edit

Comment: Take $a_n=n\log(n),\;$ Maple says the limit is $e,\;$ but unfortunately I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the limit when $a_n=n^{c}$ with $c\gt1$ is $\mathrm e^c$, the first idea that comes to mind is to try $a_n=n\log n$. Behold! This works.

*Proof:* $a_{n+1}=(n+1)\log n+O(1)$ hence $\frac{a_{n+1}+1}{a_n}=1+\frac1n+o\left(\frac1{n}\right)$.