# $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup_{k \geqslant n} (\frac{1+a_{k+1}}{a_k})^k \geqslant e$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove: $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup_{k \geqslant n} (\frac{1+a_{k+1}}{a_k})^k \geqslant e$$ for any sequence $\{a_n\}$ where $a_n > 0$.

I made a likely proof myself, but it's so complicated that Wolframalpha couldn't recongnize it when I tried to verify it. Also my "proof" suggests that they are never equal, so I really doubt it. Even if it was correct, it was not remotely near the optimized one. Could you please give me a better proof?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/747987/42969

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/580609/42969